# How to store Drop down Value in Hidden field for external js File

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using External .JS file in my project. and I want to store Drop down Value in Hidden field on change event of Drop down.
My drop down is separate from JS file as obvious which is Present in ASPX page.

Can Any one help me on same.

Scince i am using Hidden Field So Firstly i need to access Hidden field for that I have Written as

```
<script>
        var hdnObjectIDClientId = <%=hdnCountry.ClientID%>;
 </script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCountry" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Just Before JS file reference in ASPX page

and In Js File i have written code :

```
 $('#ddlCountry').change(function (e) {
        $('#hdnObjectIDClientId').val(this.value);
        BindCompanies();

    });
```

But on console window its showing Error :

**Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference**

Here I have Attached Console windows Screen shots

[image: Please Look this]
How i have Written code in ASPX Page

[image: Here i have attached Screenshots of my aspx code]

Comment: Looks like `hdnObjectIDClientId` is plain text when you want the value it is bound to. Did you try `$('#' + hdnObjectIDClientId).val(this.value);`

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky I tried as you suggested but still its showing hdnObjectIDClient|ID is undefined